# How to fix the timeout problem in curl::curl_fetch_memory when using R with a proxy?

Tags: r, curl, proxy, quantmod

I have seen many questions on `curl`'s timeout problem. However, I am still confused about my case.

My problem occurred when I was using `quantmod::getSymbols`. Every trial ended up with

```
Warning message:
x = 'AAPL', get = 'stock.prices': Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(cu, handle = h): Timeout was reached: [finance.yahoo.com] Operation timed out after 10008 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received
```

Note I am using a proxy. I have tried to switch on and off the proxy or run

```
httr::set_config(httr::use_proxy(
  "127.0.0.1:xxxxxx", port = 8080,
  username = "xxxx", password = "****"
), override = TRUE)
```

However, nothing works.

After getting confused about `quantmod`'s internal details, I decided to experiment on the pure `curl_fetch_memory`.

1. the example in `curl_fetch_memory`'s document works normally on my computer

```
curl::curl_fetch_memory("http://httpbin.org/cookies/set?foo=123&bar=ftw")
```

2. `curl_fetch_memory` does not work for `"https://finance.yahoo.com/"` (Note that I cannot get access to the website on a web browser without my proxy)
3. The followings codes can successfully fetch results from https://finance.yahoo.com/:

```
curl_opts <- list(
  ssl_verifypeer = 0L,
  proxyuserpwd = "xxxx:****",
  proxyauth = as.integer(15),
  proxy = "127.0.0.1:xxxxxx",
  proxyport = 8080
)
cookie_handler <- curl::new_handle()
curl::handle_setopt(handle=cookie_handler, .list=curl_opts)

curl::curl_fetch_memory("https://finance.yahoo.com/",
                        handle = cookie_handler)
```

It seems that `quantmod` is unable to use the proxy setting properly. However, there is no option to set the proxy inside the functions from the package. How can I solve my problem?

*System:*

```
R version 4.1.1 (2021-08-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19043)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936 
[2] LC_CTYPE=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                              
[5] LC_TIME=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936   

# ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I have found the solution. All you need is to switch on the proxy and run

```
Sys.setenv(ALL_PROXY = "YOUR_PROXY_HOST")
```

before the request.

However, currently I still have no idea of how the `curl` uses the setting `ALL_PROXY`. I would appreciate it if anyone can offer it an explanation.